# Getter method new BigNumber() not a base 16 number error

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

Why does this produce an error?
If I change the name variable to type uint etc (instead of trying to get a string), the code works.
This seems like a bug.

Contract:

```
//define which compiler to use
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract MyFirstContract {
  string public name = "billy";

  function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
    return name;
  }
}
```

DApp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@metamask/detect-provider/dist/detect-provider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  App = {

    web3Provider: null,
    contracts: {},
    accounts: null,
    instance: null,

    initWeb3: async function() {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
        try {
          // Request account access
          App.accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
          console.log(App.accounts[0]);
          console.log("Access granted!");
        } catch (error) {
          // User denied account access...
          console.error("Access denied!")
        }
      }
    },

    initContract: function() {
      $.getJSON('MyFirstContract.json', function(data) {
        // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with @truffle/contract
        var Artifact = data;
        App.contracts.MyFirstContract = TruffleContract(Artifact);
        // Set the provider for our contract
        App.contracts.MyFirstContract.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
        return App.initDeploy();
      });
    },

    initDeploy: async function() {
      App.instance = await App.contracts.MyFirstContract.deployed();
      return App.initGetName();
    },

    initGetName: async function() {
      let result = await App.instance.getName({from: App.accounts[0]});
    },

  }

  App.initWeb3();
  App.initContract();

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Output:

```
0xd9f4da794a6aa9dd7779579dc4306733749589ad
(index):30 Access granted!
web3.min.js:4 **Uncaught (in promise) BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number**: 
    at O (http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:4:30186)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:5:3886
    at new e (http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:4:27683)
    at i.w [as _outputFormatter] (http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:1:9973)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:1:14661
    at i.decode (http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:1:14683)
    at http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:1:7489
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at d.decodeParams (http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:1:7462)
    at c.unpackOutput (http://localhost:3000/js/web3.min.js:2:6179)
O @ web3.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:5
e @ web3.min.js:4
w @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
i.decode @ web3.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:1
d.decodeParams @ web3.min.js:1
c.unpackOutput @ web3.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ web3.min.js:2
_handle @ inpage.js:17
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
write @ inpage.js:1
w @ inpage.js:17
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:17
y.write @ inpage.js:17
g @ inpage.js:17
f @ inpage.js:8
o.emit @ inpage.js:8
_ @ inpage.js:17
v @ inpage.js:17
w.push @ inpage.js:17
_write @ inpage.js:1
w @ inpage.js:17
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:17
y.write @ inpage.js:17
g @ inpage.js:1
f @ inpage.js:8
o.emit @ inpage.js:8
_ @ inpage.js:1
v @ inpage.js:1
w.push @ inpage.js:1
_onData @ inpage.js:1
_onMessage @ inpage.js:1
postMessage (async)
_postMessage @ contentscript.js:1
_write @ contentscript.js:1
w @ contentscript.js:1
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:1
y.write @ contentscript.js:1
g @ contentscript.js:17
d @ contentscript.js:8
o.emit @ contentscript.js:8
_ @ contentscript.js:17
v @ contentscript.js:17
w.push @ contentscript.js:17
_write @ contentscript.js:17
w @ contentscript.js:17
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:17
y.write @ contentscript.js:17
g @ contentscript.js:17
d @ contentscript.js:8
o.emit @ contentscript.js:8
_ @ contentscript.js:17
v @ contentscript.js:17
w.push @ contentscript.js:17
_write @ contentscript.js:17
w @ contentscript.js:17
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:17
y.write @ contentscript.js:17
g @ contentscript.js:17
d @ contentscript.js:8
o.emit @ contentscript.js:8
_ @ contentscript.js:17
v @ contentscript.js:17
w.push @ contentscript.js:17
_onMessage @ contentscript.js:8
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:8
Show 33 more frames
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway. After many, many hours. I tried,
truffle migrate --reset.
And it just magically started working...